# clangd language server gives weird errors. code compiles

Tags: c++, std, stdvector, clangd

I've got platformio project that compiles and works.
Using emacs + lsp-mode + clang.
One of the weird errors I get is for structures like this:

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

struct test_v{
    std::vector<int> buff;
};
```

on the line `#include <queue>`

```
in included file: no type named 'pointer' in 'std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int>>'
```

on the line of buff definition

```
In template: no member named 'value' in 'std::is_void<int>'
```

file is `.hpp` in case this matters

Answer (score 0):

the config was incomplete and missing headers that define the needed std:: parts